# Make an array function of javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a function like an array?
so that the following functions can become simple and be easily edited.

```
function q1() {
  var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
  var quantity = theForm.elements["q1"];
  var howmany = 0;
  if (quantity.value != "") {
    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
  }
  return howmany;
}

function q2() {
  var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
  var quantity = theForm.elements["q2"];
  var howmany = 0;
  if (quantity.value != "") {
    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
  }
  return howmany;
}

function q3() {
  var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
  var quantity = theForm.elements["q3"];
  var howmany = 0;
  if (quantity.value != "") {
    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
  }
  return howmany;
}
```

now i changed like this
GetQuantity() is used to get the value from the Qty field. e.g. q_A01..
GetPrice() is used to get the readonly value Price field. e.g. p_A01..
calculateTotal() is used to calculate the totalprice and return to the field ID "Total".

```
function GetQuantity(e) {
var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
var quantity = theForm.elements[e];
var howmany =0;
if(quantity.value!=0) {
howmany = parseInt(quantity.value); }
return howmany;
}
function GetPrice(e) {
    var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
    var price = theForm.elements[e];
    var howmany =0;
    if(price.value!=0) {
    howmany = parseInt(price.value); }
    return howmany;
    }

function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice =
GetPrice(p_A01)*GetQuantity(q_A01)+
GetPrice(p_A02)*GetQuantity(q_A02)+
GetPrice(p_A03)*GetQuantity(q_A03)+
GetPrice(p_F11)*GetQuantity(q_F11);

  var Totalordered = document.getElementById ("Total");
         Totalordered.value = cakePrice;


}
```

Comment: You could certainly write it shorter, maybe just `function fetch() { return 0 }` as they all return the same thing ?

Comment: when only 1 things changes, a `switch` or even an object lookup table would be more apropos.

Comment: I suppose that your function should return `return quantity.length` not `howmany`

Comment: sorry everyone. i missed a script to post. it's updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why none of the answer suggested the obvious - keep the common code in the function body, and make the changeable code a function parameter:

```
function q(e) {
  var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
  var quantity = theForm.elements[e];
  var howmany = 0;
  if (quantity.value != "") {
    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
  }
  return howmany;
}
```

or a shorter version, almost identical to your original one:

```
function q(e) {
  var quantity = document.forms["contact-form"].elements[e];
  return (quantity && quantity.value) || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your functions do the same thing. Just pass the varying data into a single function:

```
function q1(qty) {   
   var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
   var howmany = 0;
   // Do whatever you need to with the qty argument.
   return howmany;
}
```

But interestingly, the one thing that varies (quantity) is is something your functions don't actually do anything with.

This is the fundamental premise of functions in any programming language and the basis for the general best-practice principle of DRY (don't repeat yourself). Since all your functions do the same thing, just take what varies (quantity) and separate that out of the function. Now, you don't have 5 functions to store and maintain.

Comment: many thanks to all guys replied to my question. i missed a script. sorry about that. now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use one function for all the inputs just pass the input id or name in it and get values of that element.

```js
var q = 'q2';
function qty(q1) {
        var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
        var quantity = theForm.elements[q1]; var howmany =0;
    return howmany;
}
    document.write(qty(q));
```

Comment: thanks Hitesh, thanks every guys, thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi check the following code as you updated   
  function GetQuantity(e) {
        var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
        var quantity = theForm.elements[e];
        var howmany =0;
        if(quantity.value!=0) {
        howmany = parseInt(quantity.value); }
        return howmany;
    }
    function GetPrice(e) {
        var theForm = document.forms["contact-form"];
        var price = theForm.elements[e];
        var howmany =0;
        if(price.value!=0) {
        howmany = parseInt(price.value); }
        return howmany;
        }

    function calculateTotal()
    {
        var cakePrice =
    GetPrice('p_A01')*GetQuantity('q_A01')+
    GetPrice('p_A02')*GetQuantity('q_A02')+
    GetPrice('p_A03')*GetQuantity('q_A03')+
    GetPrice('p_F11')*GetQuantity('q_F11');

      var Totalordered = document.getElementById ("Total");
             Totalordered.value = cakePrice;


    }
            calculateTotal();
```